# Is it possible to approximate all angles with certain pythagorean triples?

Tags: trigonometry, approximation, triangles, geometric-construction

With sticks $a,b$ and $c$ of length $3,4$ and $5$, you able to draw a [right (tri)angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle). But are also able to construct an angle $\cos\alpha=\frac35, \alpha=\arccos(\frac35)=$[$53.13010...^°$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcos%283%2F5%29).

> Is it possible to approximate all angles with certain pythagorean triples?

And given an $\alpha$ and an $\epsilon$, how to get the example with smallest numbers $a,b,c$, such that $\alpha\pm \epsilon=\arccos \frac ac$?

Comment: You just have to show that $2mn/(m^2+n^2)$ is dense in $(0,1)$. Or work with $(m^2-n^2)/(m^2+n^2)$, if that's easier.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson:  seems likely enough.  Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Pythagorean triangle has sides $2mn$, $m^2-n^2$, $m^2+n^2$ for some integers $m\gt n\gt0$. One of its angles has cosine equal to $${m^2-n^2\over m^2+n^2}=1-2{1\over(m/n)^2+1}$$ Now $m/n$ is dense in $(1,\infty)$, so that cosine is dense in $(0,1)$.

Comment: thanks, a proof of density was what I had in mind. Partially... do think it's possible to say something about the minimal examples $m,n$ for $\alpha\pm \epsilon=\arccos\frac{m^2-n^2}{m^2+n^2}$ and/or how to get them?

Comment: Solve $a=\arccos(1-2((m/n)^2+1)^{-1}$ for $m/n$, you'll find you are trying to find a rational approximation $m/n$ to some given number, and continued fractions will give you the answer --- but it will depend on the continued fraction expansion of the number, so it won't be simple (except in simple cases).